# Permission creating taxonomy terms per vocabulary

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, users

Is there a module that will allow me to allow a specific role to create/edit/delete terms in a specific vocabulary without allowing them to edit the taxonomy itself or terms on another vocabulary?

The only taxonomy permission I see is "administer taxonomy", which is decidedly more than I want to give those users.  My google-fu turned up numerous modules that will permission the nodes by terms, but none that allow permissioning of the vocabulary itself.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 6, this looks like the module for you: [Vocabulary Permissions Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/vppr)